# Firebase cloud functions throws timeout exception but standalone works fine

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to call a third party API using my Firebase cloud functions. I have billing enabled and all my other function are working fine.

However, I have one method that throws **Timeout** exception when it tries to call third API. The interesting thing is, when I run the same method from a standalone nodeJS file, it works fine. But when I deploy it on Firebase cloud or start the function locally, it shows timeout error.

**Following is my function:**

```
exports.fetchDemo = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, response) => 
{
    var res = {};
    res.started = true;
    await myMethod();
    res.ended = true;
    response.status(200).json({ data: res });
});

async function myMethod() {
     var url = 'my third party URL';
     console.log('Line 1');
     const res = await fetch(url);
     console.log('Line 2'); // never prints when run with cloud functions
     var data = await res.text();
     console.log(`Line 3: ${data}`);
}
```

Just now I also noticed, when I hit the same URL in the browser it gives the following exception. It means, it works only with standalone node.

```
<errorDTO>
  <code>INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR</code>
 <uid>c0bb83ab-233c-4fe4-9a9e-3f10063e129d</uid>
</errorDTO>
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: There is no way we can help you without seeing your code, along with your debugging details (logs, observations, etc).  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: my bad... just added the code.

Comment: That doesn't look like complete Cloud Functions code.  There should be enough information in the question that anyone can use to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: I don't need a URL.  I need to see the code that isn't working the way you expect.  Please see again: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The myMethod is the one which is not working. I mean, it throws timeout when it calls the fetch method. However the same method works fine without cloud.

Comment: You said that this code is running in Cloud Functions.  We need to see the complete function declaration along with the code in its callback.  Without that, there's nothing we can do, as we can't trace the code execution from start to finish.

Comment: Can you show the specific log output?  What is the exception that's thrown?

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson my colleague just informed me that he wrote a new method with the name fetch. I was not aware about it. So when my method was calling to the fetch method, it was actually calling his method he wrote down the file. I just tool git update and did not notice he wrote this method. I am really sorry wasting your time. I appreciate your time and help and thanks for being helpful every time...

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that one of my colleague wrote a new method with the name fetch. I was not aware about it. So when my method was calling to the fetch method, it was actually calling his method he wrote down the file. I just took git update and did not notice he wrote this method.